# Do Biblical Unitarians have a theology and definition of divine simplicity?

Tags: nature-of-god, biblical-unitarian, divine-simplicity

> The doctrine of divine simplicity says that God is simple (without
> parts). The general idea can be stated in this way: The being of God
> is identical to the "attributes" of God. Characteristics such as
> omnipresence, goodness, truth, eternity, etc., are identical to God's
> being, not qualities that make up that being, nor abstract entities
> inhering in God as in a substance; in other words we can say that in
> God both essence and existence are one and the same. - [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divine_simplicity)

> Divine simplicity is central to the classical Western concept of God. Simplicity denies any physical or metaphysical composition in the divine being. This means God is the divine nature itself and has no accidents (properties that are not necessary) accruing to his nature. There are no real divisions or distinctions in this nature. Thus, the entirety of God is whatever is attributed to him. - [Internet Encyclopedia of Philosophy](https://iep.utm.edu/divine-simplicity/)

Simply put Divine Simplicity says that God is **all** of his attributes with no subdivision.  God is 100% love, 100% just, 100% merciful, etc.  Whatever attributes can rightly be attributed to God, He is all of each of them with no displacement of one by another.

Do Biblical Unitarians hold a concept of a divinely simple God?  Does it differ in any way from the above?

Related:
[Does divine simplicity imply that God is identical to his attributes?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/53993/does-divine-simplicity-imply-that-god-is-identical-to-his-attributes)

[What is the Biblical basis for divine simplicity?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/5281/what-is-the-biblical-basis-for-divine-simplicity)

Comment: Would be interested to know where you're coming from on this - why do you think it's important for BUs? I can't recall reading anything from BUs that addresses this, and nothing comes up in a quick search, so some significant digging might be required.

Comment: It's fairly fundamental in Western Christianity's concept of God, although there are some different nuances and the roots of it predate Christianity in Greek thought.  It's a way to explain, for instance, that God's love and justice are not at war within Him...He is all of both and neither is diminished by the other.  It adds a weight to statements like God is love.

Comment: Ya, but I'm wondering how you think this relates to BU in particular?

Comment: If an answer appears then I will know how it relates to BU in particular.  Currently I don't know.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. If you had a specific issue you thought it connected to, I could look up that issue and then see how it relates.

Comment: My guess is there are a variety of views on this, just as with Trinitarianism.

Comment: @OneGodtheFather I will be very surprised if there is no BU thought on this.